# The Discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is a $T_1$ space and not limit point Compact

Tags: general-topology

I was hoping someone could review my proofs below. I'm not totally sure both statements are true (or even if one of them is true). Thanks!

Statement 1:

> $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology is a $T_1$ space

Statement 2:

> The discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is not limit point compact.

**Proof of statement 1:**

We wish to show that finite sets are closed. It suffices to show that single point sets are closed, since then the finite union of closed singletons will produce a closed finite set.

Take any set $\{a\}$. Then $X - \{a\} = (-\infty, a) \cup (a,\infty)$. 
Since each set in the above union is open as it can be written as the infinite union of the open singleton points inside each set, we have that $X - \{a\}$ is open. Hence $\{a\}$ is closed. 
Hence any finite set is closed.

**Proof of statement 2:**

Let $X$ be the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Take the interval $[0,1]$. This interval is infinite. The interval also contains no limit points since for any proposed limit point $x$, we can take the open set $\{x\}$ as an open set that does not intersect $[0,1]$ in any place other than itself. Hence $X$ is not limit point compact.

Comment: just a note, "the discrete topology on R" itself is not a space. One should rather write "$\mathbb R$ with the discrete topology is a T1 space".

Comment: Both statements are true and your proofs are correct! You can simplify them by generalising this to any space with the discrete topology (hint: every subset of a space with the discrete topology is both closed and open)

Comment: we could also claim that R with the discrete topology is countably compact right? @nammie

Comment: @H_1317 any (infinite) space with the discrete topology is not countably compact. You can prove this directly (as every set is open), or use that in $T1$ spaces, countably compact and limit point compact are equivalent.

Comment: ah i see, u can still create open sets (a,b) in the discrete topology by unioning all points in (a,b) from their singleton open basis elements ... and then u can use the integers (take open sets where a and b are integer values) to create a countable open covering. sound correct for a counterexample? @nammie

Comment: Yes! The intervals $(n, n+2)$ form an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ with no finite subcover in both the discrete topology and the usual Euclidean one.